# Longest vowel substring - Python

Tags: python, string

This is a challenge from Kata. The function should return the max amount of subsequent vowels in a string.

I found this really practical solution after completing it myself.

Can someone explain the code step by step? I would like to thoroughly understand how the join and split bits complete each other here.

```
def solve(string):
    return max(map(len, ''.join(i if i in 'aeiou' else ' ' for i in string).split()))
```

Comment: Although not an answer. The code provided is indeed not easily understandable. I would personally go for a multiline `max(map(len, re.findall(r'[aeiou]+', string)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing to do in these cases is to simplify and divide into smaller parts. The `join` is simply joining together a sequence of strings composed by either a vowel or an empty space from the conditional generator comprehension:

```
s = 'aei234roieeieigfh'

out1 = ''.join(i if i in 'aeiou' else ' ' for i in s)
# 'aei    oieeiei   '
```

The above is just a fancy way of writting the following generator function:

```
def f(s):
    for i in s:
        if i in 'aeiou':
            yield i
        else:
            yield ' '

''.join(f(s))
# 'aei    oieeiei   '
```

Then by splitting you get a list of strings as:

```
out2 = out1.split()
# ['aei', 'oieeiei']
```

Then by mapping with the `len`, you're taking the `len` of each item in the list:

```
list(map(len, out2))
# [3, 7]
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
[len(i) for i in out2]
# [3, 7]
```

And finally by taking the `max` you'll find the longest sequence of vowels in the list.

---

I personally would go with `itertools.groupby` here :)

```
max(len(list(v)) for k,v in groupby(s, key=lambda x: x in 'aeiou') if k)
# 7
```

---

Some reads you might find useful:

- [Understanding generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)
- [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)